# How force change Finder icons for file types?

Tags: finder, icon

I've read so many answers to this question, but none of them seem to work in the latest Mac OS Ventura 13.1

File icons keep getting the wrong thumbnail. As soon as you install some software that uses the same file associations as previously installed software, all your icons get changed to that new software, without asking.

You can change the file association via GET INFO, but the wrong icon remains. Steps to reproduce:

- install vs code (JS icons become associated with VS code)
- install phpstorm (JS icons become associated with phpstorm)
- GET INFO
- change file type association back to VS code, apply to all files
- now the JS file DOES get opened with VS code by default, but the icon remains a phpstorm icon!

Restarting the finder or the whole mac has no effect.

[image: wrongicon]